# How to make "cd" with arch-chroot non-interactive in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, command, chroot

I can't run this command in Arch Linux. I need to change directory in a chroot.

```
#arch-chroot /mnt cd /tmp
chroot: failed to run command cd - No such file or directory
```

In interactive mode of chroot it works fine.

Comment: What exactly do you imagine the effect will be? You'll enter the chroot, go to that directory, exit the chroot... then what?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, it is not a command available for `arch-chroot` to run (see `type -a cd`). Compare it to `arch-chroot /mnt ls /tmp`. You can use `cd` in a shell, e.g. `arch-chroot /mnt sh -c 'cd /tmp'`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this:
`arch-chroot /mnt && cd /tmp` else the `chroot` command will think that **cd** is a directory.